# Navigate cursor to textarea (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx

When the user clicks on the blue text, the textArea should become active and navigate user to the right position.
[image]

I already know how to navigate the user to the right position with textArea.positionCaret(). But I dont know how to active the textArea so the user sees where the cursor is right now. Has somebody an idea how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `textArea.requestFocus()`?

Comment: thank you very much!!!! Its working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with textArea.requestFocus()